# How to add internal methods inside vanilla js web components?

Tags: javascript, web-component

There is a task - to insert a reusable piece of code into a vanilla JS component.

```js
class Plane extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }
  connectedCallback() {
    if (!this.rendered) {
      this.render();
      this.rendered = true;
    }
  }
  render() {
    this.innerHTML = plane.innerHTML + plane_styles.innerHTML;
  }
}
window.customElements.define('plane-scheme', Plane);

const plane = document.createElement('plane');
plane.className = 'plane';
plane.innerHTML = `...`;

document.body.append(plane);
```

Everything works great. However, in addition to the HTML element itself, several information handler functions must be included along with it. So far I don't quite understand how to implement it. I tried to make an arrow function inside the constructor, add it as a separate method - zero effect. How to implement it correctly?

Comment: What is something you want to add? What is an example of one of these "several information handler functions"

Answer (score 0):

Custom Elements **are** Classes, so learn: https://javascript.info/class

```js
customElements.define('a-plane', class extends HTMLElement {
  connectedCallback() {
    this.innerHTML = `A <span>${this.planetype}</span>`;
    this.onclick = (evt) => this.fly();
  }
  get planetype() {                     // GETTER
    return this.getAttribute("type");
  }
  set planetype(val) {                  // SETTER
    if(!this.isConnected) console.error("I am not in the DOM yet");
    this.setAttribute("type", val);
    this.querySelector("span").innerHTML = val;
  }
  fly() {                               // METHOD
    this.classList.toggle("flying");
  }
});

const plane = document.createElement('a-plane');
document.body.append(plane);
plane.planetype = "Airbus"; // set After! the element is in the DOM
```

```css
a-plane {
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.flying {
  background: skyblue
}
a-plane.flying:after {
  content: " flying"
}
```

```html
<a-plane type="Boeing"></a-plane>
<a-plane type="Fokker"></a-plane>
```